# Globalizing UIAlertView

Tags: ios, xcode

I was wondering, if I alloc a UIAlertView in view controllerA, can I access its response from Viewcontroller B?

e.g.

ViewController A

```
UIAlertView *alert;
alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
[alert setTitle:@"Confirm"];
[alert setMessage:@"Do you pick Yes or No?"];
[alert setDelegate:self];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Yes"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"No"];
[alert show];
```

Viewcontroller B

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if (alertView == alert)
{

}
}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: You could simply make viewcontroller B the delegate for the UIAlertView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the alert view's delegate to ViewController B, then yes.

```
[alert setDelegate:self];
```

becomes

```
[alert setDelegate:viewControllerB];
```

An example from a codebase I'm working on:

```
// Creating the view controller
AreaListController *descendentAreas = [[AreaListController alloc] init];

// Setting the delegate
[alert setDelegate:descendentAreas];

// Pushing the view controller
[self pushViewController:descendentAreas];
```

Comment: and how do I initialize viewcontrollerB? sorry for my ignorance

Comment: The same way you initialize anything else, but with the addition of either [pushViewController:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/pushViewController:animated:) or the equivalent for segues (sorry, used to an old codebase and don't know that bit).

Answer (score 0):

Create a swift file like MyAlertView.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
|
class MyAlertView{
class func showIt(title: String,message: String) -> UIAlertView{
let alert : UIAlertView!
alert.delegate = self
alert.title = title
alert.message = message
alert.addButtonWithTitle("Cancel")
alert.addButtonWithTitle("Done")
alert.show
return alert
}
```

and access it in any viewcontroller like so

```
MyAlertView.showIt(title: "I'm Title",message: "I'm Message").delegate = self
```